Set docker port mapping when debugging ASP.NET Core Web API
I created an ASP.NET Core Web API project with docker support as follows:

Each time the docker container gets created, the port mapping changes

...and changes...

...and changes.

I am not able to figure out how to set the port mapping in Visual Studio so that the container always launches with the same port mapping when I start debugging. Can anyone help?
Note: I already tried to add docker compose support but this ended up in having two mappings 8080:<random> and 8080:<what i defined> when running the docker port command - and it didn't work.
Comment on solution
As the symptoms were really misleading for me, the following comment might help others: It was enough to run the project with DockerfileRunArguments enabled once to get rid of the duplicate port mapping issue when using docker compose!

In your project properties add the next:
<PropertyGroup>
    ...
    <DockerfileRunArguments>-p 5001:8080</DockerfileRunArguments>
</PropertyGroup>

It will allow you to access your web app via port 5001 during the debug
http://localhost:5001/api/
Just make sure that your port mapping does match to what says in the docker file with EXPOSE command.
Here is some info about properties that you can use - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/container-msbuild-properties?view=vs-2022

Two things: The app is a .NET 8 app, so it listens on port 8080, not 80. And EXPOSE is only documentation and does nothing, so it doesn't matter if it's there or not - or indeed if it's correct or not.

Agreed about EXPOSE. About 8080 it's only default ports, but you are not limited only to 8080.

You can see in the screenshots of the running containers that they listen on 8080, so they're using the default.

Updated my answer to match 8080 what author is using.

Thanks - now also the docker compose port mapping is applied correctly (even when removing the mentioned line). It seems that when applied once, VS2022 overrides/corrects something.

If you're running a single container:
I'd recommend instead setting httpPort in the launch profile:
"Container (Dockerfile)": {
  "commandName": "Docker",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "launchUrl": "{Scheme}://{ServiceHost}:{ServicePort}",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORTS": "8080"
  },
  "publishAllPorts": false,
  "httpPort": 5001,
  "useSSL": false
}

This has the benefit of the launch URL also getting updated implicitly.
If you're running using the compose tools you can update the port bindings in docker-compose.override.yml:
webapplication25:
  environment:
    - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    - ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORTS=8080
  ports:
    - "5001:8080"

